# Problem in adding a `Layout` to another `Layout` from java code

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a `Vertical Linear Layout`(say `rootLayout`) as a parent.
Now i wanna create another `Horizontal Linear Layout`(say `childLayout`) which i want to add this to `rootLayout`(Which is vertical).

Before this i wanna create some `TextView`, `EditText` etc which will be added to `childLayout`(which is Horizontal).

Here is my code:

```
LinearLayout childLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
        rootLayout.addView(childLayout);
        childLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        childLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsLl = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        childLayout.setLayoutParams(paramsLl);


        EditText am = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
        TextView du = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        TextView oh = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        TextView ml = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        EditText ap = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
        TextView pd = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
        EditText nm = new EditText(MainActivity.this);



        childLayout.addView(nm);
        childLayout.addView(pd);
        childLayout.addView(ap);
        childLayout.addView(ml);
        childLayout.addView(am);
        childLayout.addView(du);
        childLayout.addView(oh);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsNm = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                0,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                100
        );
        nm.setHint("Enter Name");
        nm.setHintTextColor(Color.rgb(Integer.parseInt("eb", 16),
                Integer.parseInt("24", 16), Integer.parseInt("05", 16)));
        nm.setTextColor(Color.rgb(Integer.parseInt("eb", 16),
                Integer.parseInt("24", 16), Integer.parseInt("05", 16)));
        nm.setId(boarders.size() + 1);
        nm.setLayoutParams(paramsNm);


        LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsPd = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                0,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                30
        );
        pd.setText("0.0");
        pd.setLayoutParams(paramsPd);
        pd.setId(500 + boarders.size() + 1);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsPm = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                0,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                30
        );
        ap.setId(1000 + boarders.size() + 1);
        ap.setLayoutParams(paramsPm);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsMl = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                0,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                30
        );
        ml.setText("0.0");
        ml.setLayoutParams(paramsMl);
        ml.setId(1500 + boarders.size() + 1);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsAm = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                0,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                30
        );
        am.setId(2000 + boarders.size() + 1);
        am.setLayoutParams(paramsAm);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsDu = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                0,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                30
        );
        du.setText("0.0");
        du.setLayoutParams(paramsDu);
        du.setId(2500 + boarders.size() + 1);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsOh = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                0,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                30
        );
        oh.setText("0.0");
        oh.setLayoutParams(paramsOh);
        oh.setId(3000 + boarders.size() + 1);
```

But Problem is, this `childLayout` doesn't fit of width as `MATCH_PARENT`. Rather it is placed in half of the width of the `parLayout`.

[image]

As the picture given above, the marked one is `childLayout`. As you see it is not placing the whole width of the `parLayout`.
I want this `childLayout` to place in whole width of `parLayout`.

how can i solve this??

Sorry for so many lines of code. pardon me for this.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the lines with

**LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsOh = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 30);**

to

LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsOh = new ***LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 30);***

Comment: Slightly changed, but still it is not fitting to MATCH_PARENT

Comment: Try ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT instead of LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT

Comment: Thank you for your answer dear mam!
But still no change! :( :(

Comment: I meant you need to replace all the lines with width set as 0 to ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT.